# How to make HTML table from JSON objects data

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I am trying to create an **HTML table** from **JSON objects** data with a `for` loop in a function. Below is the key part of my code that is clearly not working as intended and I am struggling to figure it out.

```
var table = ''

var forLoopData = function() {
  for (j=0; j<dataJson.length; j++) {
    table += '<tr';

    for(var i=0; i<6; i++)  {
      table += "<td>" dataJson[i].id "</td>" "<td>"dataJson[i].firstName"</td>" "<td>"dataJson[i].lastName"</td>" "<td>"dataJson[i].dateOfBirth"</td>" "<td>"dataJson[i].function"</td>" "<td>"dataJson[i].experience"</td>";
    }

    table += </tr>
  }
};

forLoopData();
document.write('<table>' + table + '</table>');
```

Comment: Typo: `table += '<tr'` is missing the closing `>`.

Comment: And `table += </tr>` is missing quotes.

Comment: You're missing all the concatenation operators on the `table += "<td>"` line. You have to use `+` to concatenate strings with variables, you can't just put them next to each other like that. You really need to read a Javascript tutorial to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Your table lacks the table, tbody and tr tags.

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>dataJson[i].id</td>
          <td>dataJson[i].firstName</td>
          <td>dataJson[i].lastName</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what you need to build.

Here is how:

```
var table = "<table><tbody>";

for(var i=0; i<6; i++)  {
  table += "<tr>" ;
  table += "<td>" + dataJson[i].id "</td>" ;
  table += "<td>" + dataJson[i].firstName + "</td>" ;
  table += "<td>" + dataJson[i].lastName + "</td>" ;
  table += "</tr>" ;
}
table += "</tbody></table>";
```

with your table ready you can use document.write(table)

Comment: He has the table tag here: `document.write('<table>' + table + '</table>')`

Comment: He has the `tr` tag here, but with a typo: `table += '<tr';`

Comment: `<tbody>` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for trying to help me. Unfortunately I dropped this idea and did not have the chance to test your answers. Combining vanilla JavaScript with html elements is still hard for me and I decided to go with bootstrap framework. Below is code I used:

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            items.push("<tr>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.id+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.firstName+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.lastName+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.dateOfBirth+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.function+"</td>");
            items.push("<td id =''"+key+"''>"+val.experience+"</td>");
            items.push("</tr>");
        });
        $("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");   
    });
```